# Why are there three zeros followed by the value of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is the program:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},i;
    char* p;
    p=(char*)a;
    printf("%d",*p);
    for( i=0;i<32;i++)
    {
       p=p+1;
       printf("%d",*p);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Output:-

```
$ ./a.out
100020003000400050006000700080000
```

Why is the output like this?
Why are there three zeros followed by the value of the array?

`char` pointer is incremented by 1 byte. The binary representation of 1 stored in memory is 0000000 00000000 00000000 00000001.  Is that right?  So the output should be like 0 0 0 1.  If wrong please explain.

Comment: It's the value of the integer followed by three zeros, actually.

Comment: I wonder what a 32-bit int looks like in memory, byte-by-byte?

Comment: hint: despite the cast at line 6, `a` still contains int values, not char ones

Comment: Is this due in tomorrow morning?   I mean, obviously you did not write it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

`char` are generally 1 byte while `int` are generally 4 bytes. In memory if you need to increment a `char pointer` 4 times to fully increment an `int`.

Change

```
char* p;
p=(char*)a;
```

to:

```
int* p;
p=(int*)a;
```

This will delete all the zeros

Also change

```
int a[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},i;
```

to:

```
int a[9]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},i;
```

as you are not allocating enough space and change

```
printf("%d",*p);
for( i=0;i<32;i++)
{
   p=p+1;
   printf("%d",*p);
}
```

to:

```
for(i=0; i<9; i++)
{
   printf("%d",*p);
   p=p+1;
}
```

**Memory Map Visualization**
Arrays in C and most languages are just elements stored in consecutive memory locations. `int array[2] = {1,2}` will look like this in memory:

```
// Assuming array starts at location 0x000 (in hex) 
// Keep in mind a byte is 8 bits so a byte can contain values from 0x00 to 0xff
location:   value:
0x00      = [0x01] // first byte of first int 
0x01      = [0x00] // second byte of first int
0x02      = [0x00] // third byte of first int
0x03      = [0x00] // fourth byte of first int
0x04      = [0x02] // first byte of second int 
0x05      = [0x00] // second byte of second int
0x06      = [0x00] // third byte of second int
0x07      = [0x00] // fourth byte of second int
```

As you can see, `int` occupies 4 bytes. `int *` increments by 4 memory locations which will get you to the next integer value. In your case, after you increment a `char *`, you only increment a quarter of that `int` and printing out the zeros (3 of them).

If you try `int array[2] = {256, 2}` and iterate through it using `char *`, I'm sure you will print out:

`0 1 0 0 2 0 0 0`

This is because 256 equals 0x100 in thus it can't be stored in a byte and has to utilize the second byte inside the first `int`. The memory map will look like this:

```
location:   value:
0x00      = [0x00] // first byte of first int 
0x01      = [0x01] // second byte of first int
0x02      = [0x00] // third byte of first int
0x03      = [0x00] // fourth byte of first int
0x04      = [0x02] // first byte of second int 
0x05      = [0x00] // second byte of second int
0x06      = [0x00] // third byte of second int
0x07      = [0x00] // fourth byte of second int
```

Comment: why the compiler does not give any warning on such declaration int a[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},i;` ?

Comment: Depends on which compiler you use and which flags you used during compilation. I used `-Werror` and that line gave me an error.

Comment: I want to know why there are zeros coming after int value.int value is of  4 bytes and character is of 1 byte.What is the memory representation for it.

Comment: I explained the memory allocation of the array further. Please accept answer if it helped your understanding :)

Answer (score 2):

Your loop accesses 32 addresses n = 0; n < 32.
Assuming that integers occupy 4 bytes on your system, you are only accessing bytes that are the start of 4 byte integers every 4th time.

This code increments by 4 for each loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, i;
    char* p;
    p=(char*)a;

    for( i = 0; i < 32; i += 4) {
       printf("%d\t",*(p+i));
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The loop control would be more robust using this

```
for( i = 0; i < 32; i += sizeof(int)) {
```

as it would set the increment to whatever size 'integer' is on the machine it's running on.

There are other issues, including your array allocation is more than the allocated array size.

Was there a reason for not just accessing the array elements:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, i;

    for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i ++) {
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This may help you see how the integer is stored. As it's a signed value, it is likely in two's complement notation.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[8] = {1, -2147483647 ,3,4,5,6,7,8}, i;
    char* p;
    p=(char*)a;
    for( i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
       printf("%d\t",(*p));
       p++;
       if (i%4 == 3) printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Run it again after decrementing the negative number (The largest negative number for a 32 bit signed integer)
The \t and the additional printf line help format the output to make it easier to follow. Also note that p is incremented after printing, not before. In your original code you were accessing beyond the end of the bytes used in the array.

Also remove your first printf line as it confuses the output

Comment: char pointer is incremented by 1 byte.The binary representation of 1 stored in memory is 0000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 .Is that right ? so the output should be like 0 0 0 1. if wrong please explain .

Comment: @KunalKakade I don't know how integers are represented on your OS.

Comment: its Ubuntu 14.4. Tell me in yours OS? if you don't know in mine?

Answer (score 1):

This is an endian issue.

> The binary representation of 1 stored in memory is 0000000 00000000 00000000 00000001? Is that right ?

Yes - but consider *where* those bytes are stored.

> so the output should be like 0 0 0 1. if wrong please explain

Not quite and not so in OP's case.

[Let us assume the size of `int` is 4 times the size of `char` and `char` is 8 bits]

> why is the output of this c program is like this?

The *order* in memory of the 4 depends on [*endian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  In OP's cases, the least significant byte is stored in the first address followed by the remaining 3 likely in with each more significant byte in the next addressed byte.  This is *little endian*.

On another machine, the order may be reversed and in the order OP expects - this is *big endian*.

Other orderings are possible, though now rare.